# run setInterval for only 5 minutes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, steam

so I have the following code.

```
 setInterval(function(){
          steamOfferObj.getOffer({
              "tradeOfferId": tradeOfferID["tradeofferid"] // The tradeoffer id
          }, function(error, body) {
              if (error == null) {
                console.log(body);
                  if (body.response.offer.trade_offer_state == 3) {
                      return "Offer Accepted"
                  } else {
                      //on not accepted
                  }
              }
          });
      }, 5000);
```

basically it poles a steam trade offer to see if it has completed or not. However, this actually runs indefinitely, checking every 5 seconds until the program is time. What I was is for it to check every 5 seconds, for 5 minutes, after which it times out.

Any way I could go about doing that?

Comment: You have to use `clearInterval`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with interval I would to use something like this:

```
var start = Date.now();
var theInterval = setInterval(function () {
    if (Date.now() - start > 300000) {
        clearInterval(theInterval);
        return;
    }
    steamOfferObj.getOffer({
        "tradeOfferId": tradeOfferID.tradeofferid // The tradeoffer id
    }, function (error, body) {
        if (error === null) {
            console.log(body);
            if (body.response.offer.trade_offer_state == 3) {
                return "Offer Accepted";
            } else {
                //on not accepted
            }
        }
    });
}, 5000);
```

but in this case I better to use setTimeout, because you using async request:

```
var start = Date.now();

function getData() {
    if (Date.now() - start > 300000) {
        return;
    }
    steamOfferObj.getOffer({
        "tradeOfferId": tradeOfferID.tradeofferid // The tradeoffer id
    }, function (error, body) {
        setTimeout(getData, 5000);
        if (error === null) {
            console.log(body);
            if (body.response.offer.trade_offer_state == 3) {
                return "Offer Accepted";
            } else {
                //on not accepted
            }
        }
    });
}

getData();
```

Comment: Ended up using the setTimeout example you had. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

You can use `setTimeout`. For e.g

```
 var yourIntervalId = setInterval(function(){
          steamOfferObj.getOffer({
              "tradeOfferId": tradeOfferID["tradeofferid"] // The tradeoffer id
          }, function(error, body) {
              if (error == null) {
                console.log(body);
                  if (body.response.offer.trade_offer_state == 3) {
                      return "Offer Accepted"
                  } else {
                      //on not accepted
                  }
              }
          });
      }, 5000);
```

And here you clear the interval after 5 minutes (30000 ms)

```
setTimeout(function(){
    clearInterval(yourIntervalId);
}, 30000);
```

Answer (score 1):

See 1-4

first, get `start` time before setInterval called

second, save the `timer_id`

third, get `current` time when the timer called

fourth, get the time difference, when it's exceed 5 minutes, stop the timer.

```
var start = (new Date()).getTime(); // 1
var timer_id = setInterval(function(){ // 2
      var current = (new Date()).getTime(); // 3
      if((current - start)/1000 > 5*60) clearInterval(timer_id); // 4
      steamOfferObj.getOffer({
          "tradeOfferId": tradeOfferID["tradeofferid"] // The tradeoffer id
      }, function(error, body) {
          if (error == null) {
            console.log(body);
              if (body.response.offer.trade_offer_state == 3) {
                  return "Offer Accepted"
              } else {
                  //on not accepted
              }
          }
      });
  }, 5000);
```

Comment: yes, that would be better XD oh well.. someone (`Xlander`) had that answer first..

Answer (score 0):

Assign interval to a variable: var interval = setInterval; Before setInterval define current time: new Date(). Inside the interval check if 5 minutes passed. If it did, use: clearInterval(interval).

```
var now = new Date();
var intervalId = setInterval(function(){
      var currNow = new Date();
      if ((currNow-now) / 60000 > 5) {
          clearInterval(intervalId );
          return; 
      }
      steamOfferObj.getOffer({
          "tradeOfferId": tradeOfferID["tradeofferid"] // The tradeoffer id
      }, function(error, body) {
          if (error == null) {
            console.log(body);
              if (body.response.offer.trade_offer_state == 3) {
                  return "Offer Accepted"
              } else {
                  //on not accepted
              }
          }
      });
  }, 5000);
```

Comment: any Idea why you need touse Math.floor() here ?